# ¿Como hacer dos watch con composition api?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue3

estoy tratando de capturar los cambios de dos variables con composition api.

Sé que con Vue 2 se hacía de la siguiente forma:

```
watch: {
    localToData(newValue) {
      this.to = newValue
    },
    localSubjectData(newValue) {
      this.subject = newValue
    },
  },
```

Pero con composition api, lo intenté hacer de varias formas y aún no me sale

Lo intenté de la siguiente forma:

```
watch(insurerSelected, (currentValue) => {
      searchServices(currentValue)
})

watch(serviceSelected, (currentValue) => {
      searchTechnicals(currentValue)
})
```

Y no he podido dar con la solución, ¿alguien lo ha hecho?

Comment: Los objetos `insurerSelected`, `serviceSelected` son `getters`, `refs`, `reactive` o arreglos de lo anterior? Revisaste la [documentación oficial](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch)?

Comment: Son refs 

const insurerSelected = ref(null) 
const serviceSelected = ref(null) 

establece el valor de acuerdo al v-model en el select.

Comment: cuando dices *No me sale* a qué te refieres? no se disparan los watches?

Comment: que error recibes? o por que dices que no te sale?

Comment: Simplemente, todo se realizaba al mismo tiempo, es decir, si cambiaba la variable del primer watch también reaccionaba el segundo watch, al final lo termine resolviendo estableciendo un solo watch en el primer select y un onchange que me afectara el segundo select.